# AJAX PHP MYSQL Query - only show results IF and sum results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create a query to do a few things. I am new to a lot of this and am not sure what to use to get desired results. I want to query a date range (check: I can do that), BUT I only want to show results that do not have a number "0" within the date range(IE I do not want that range as a result).

Sorry if this gets confusing, I am trying to learn and it's just slow for me. I am not sure if this is something I need to do with javascript or PHP or my query itself. Most of this has been pieced together after lots and lots of searching.

I also want to Sum the amount of 'POINTS' within that date range and the lowest current 'NUMBER' within that date range. Here is my current setup:

Script to run the action:

```
function(start, end, label) {
            console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            var checkin = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var checkout = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  $(function(){
        $("#initialform").on("submit", function(formSubmit){
            $.ajax({
              url: "action.php",
              type: "POST",
              data:{"checkin":checkin, "checkout":checkout},
              success: function(data) {   
            $('#test').html(data);
            }
          })
            return false;
        });
```

action.php

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE staydate >= '$checkin' 
AND staydate < '$checkout
```

SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7a257/2

Current DataTable:

| ID | RESORT | ROOM | STAYDATE | AVAILABLE | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-12 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-13 | 3 | 20 |
| 3 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-14 | 2 | 24 |
| 4 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-15 | 5 | 24 |
| 5 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-16 | 2 | 20 |
| 6 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-17 | 0 | 20 |
| 7 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-18 | 2 | 20 |
| 8 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-19 | 0 | 20 |
| 9 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-20 | 2 | 20 |
| 10 | SSR | TS | 2021-12-21 | 1 | 24 |
| 11 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-12 | 2 | 20 |
| 12 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-13 | 3 | 20 |
| 13 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-14 | 2 | 24 |
| 14 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-15 | 5 | 24 |
| 15 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-16 | 2 | 20 |
| 16 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-17 | 4 | 20 |
| 17 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-18 | 2 | 20 |
| 18 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-19 | 5 | 20 |
| 19 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-20 | 2 | 20 |
| 20 | SSR | S9 | 2021-12-21 | 1 | 24 |

I would like to create variables within my index file so I can use these results.
If I search a range of 2021-12-14 through 2021-12-18 my desired results would be:

Resort: SSR
Sample: S9
Available: 2
Points:88

If I search 2021-12-12 through 2021-12-17 my desired results would be:

Resort: SSR
Sample: TS
Available: 2
Points: 108

And

Resort: SSR
Sample: S9
Available: 2
Points: 108

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your question... you'd like to filter and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the results based on text you type in? Do you want to filter this on the backend (PHP) or on the frontend (Javascript)?

Comment: I guess whichever is most viable taking into consideration performance, etc.The reduce looks like it would work to calculate my points. But what about removing results were available shows as 0 anywhere in the date range? Filter?

Comment: Yeah, this might be throwing you too far off where you started. But here's what I would do. Write all the code in javascript and have it do an ajax call to PHP to fetch the results. Then filter and reduce the data in javascript before you render it (react works really well for this sort of thing)

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: how so? @Strawberry

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I haven't done this before, fingers crossed, I also added to the original question....http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7a257/2

Comment: I'm confused. You're fiddle has no dates within the specified range !?!?

Comment: I'm confused as well. I didn't specify a range in the fiddle but here you go with some specified dates: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7a257/3

Comment: The data in the fiddle *still* doesn't match the 'Current DataTable' provided above. (You seem to be making this unnecessarily difficult)

Comment: the stuff in the table above was just an example and wasn't exact data. The fiddle was created from my actual database so I didn't spend half an hour inputting data. The only difference is room and sample are the same things. Everything else should match up except for the values as the ones in the question are just made up. To appease the developer gods, I have change this in my question.